# Change HDMI resolution on Nitrogen6x board with Ubuntu

Tags: display-resolution, hdmi

I started working with an Freescale i.MX6Q rev1.2 at 792 MHz a few days ago. I got the Nitrogen6X board with 2GiB DRAM and I am using an Ubuntu image from https://boundarydevices.com/.

So I connected a monitor to the HDMI port. The monitor is capable of many resolutions (I want to use the max resolution 1920x1080). The image however has not this resolution.

I connected the board via serial interface to my laptop und checked the output during the boot process. Here, U-Boot tells me, HDMI is used and resolution is set to 1024x768.

```
No panel detected: default to HDMI
Display: HDMI (1024x768)
```

I've used google and found some solutions, but they didn't work for me:

1.) I tried setting bootargs in U-Boot with

```
setenv bootargs video=mxcfb0:dev=hdmi,1920x1080M@60,if=RGB24
saveenv
boot
```

but it had no effect at all.

2.) I checked the output of `cat /sys/class/graphics/fb0/modes` which gave me the following:

```
U:1280x720p-60
U:640x480p-59
U:1280x720p-120
U:1280x720p-100
U:1920x1080p-30
U:1920x1080p-25
U:1920x1080p-24
U:1920x1080p-50
U:1440x576p-50
U:1440x576p-50
U:1440x288p-50
U:1440x288p-50
U:1280x720p-50
U:720x576p-50
U:720x576p-50
U:1920x1080p-60
U:1440x480p-60
U:1440x480p-60
U:1440x240p-60
U:1440x240p-60
U:1280x720p-60
U:720x480p-60
U:720x480p-60
U:640x480p-60
```

but I don't know how this helps me.

3.) I tried changing the resolution by navigating to `Menu->Preferences->Monitor Settings` but this tells me that no monitors are detected and therefore I can not change the resolution.

So I am still stuck to a resolution of 1024x768. How can I change it?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Dambe

Answer (score 1):

This should actually Just Work using ubuntu xenial rootfs and mainline kernel with xf86-video-armada-etnaviv.  This uses both upstream repos and Robert Nelson's repos for kernels and drivers.  Except for the 6xbootscript parts, as documented on the sabre lite page:

https://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/i.MX6+SABRE+Lite

you can more-or-less treat the nitrogen board like the wandboard page:

https://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/Wandboard

If you create the sdcard as above and make the uEnv wrapper script, you can use latest 4.10 kernel as above and you can then install various kernel images as deb packages (eg, armv7multi vs armv7multi-rt).

For imx6 video just "apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-armada-etnaviv" and your choice of desktop (as documented on the wandboard page).

I'm adding and tweaking packages for this stuff in meta-small-arm-extra but it's not very optimized yet (Robert's ubuntu stuff works out of the box if done right).